# Show that if $X$ has a countable dense subset, every collection of disjoint open sets in $X$ is countable.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Show that if $X$ has a countable dense subset, every collection of disjoint open sets in $X$ is countable.

Attempt:Let $U=\{U_i\}$ be a collection of disjoint open sets in $X$ that is countable. Let $A$ be a countable dense subset in $X$. Let $U_i \in U$. Then $U_i \cap A \neq \varnothing$, since $\overline A=X$. Since $U_i \cap U_j =\varnothing$ for each $i \neq j$, $U_i,U_j$ contain different elements of $A$.So there is a one to one correspondence between elements in $U$ and subsets of $A$. So $U$ is countable, since the result holds for any collection of disjoint open sets.

Comment:I am struggling to think of why each element of $U$ being associated with a corresponding subset of $A$ means $U$ is countable. Would it be correct that the intersection of each $U_i$ and $A$ partition the set $A$. Are there any issues with my attempt at a proof for this?Also I now see that it is wrong to say the collection of intersections of elements in $U$ with $A$ must contain the whole set $A$, since the result must hold for any collection of disjoint open sets.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to **prove** that every family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open subsets of $X$ is countable, you certainly can’t start by assuming that you have a countable family of open sets. Even before you know just where you’re going, the natural way to start is something like this:

> Let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $X$, and let $\mathscr{U}$ be a family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open subsets of $X$; we want to prove that $\mathscr{U}$ is countable.

Your next step, however, was in the right direction, though it can be phrased rather better:

> Since $D$ is dense in $X$, and each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ is non-empty, for each $U\in\mathscr{U}$ there is an $x_U\in U\cap D$.

Now you have in effect a function from $\mathscr{U}$ to $D$.

> Let $\varphi:\mathscr{U}\to D:U\mapsto x_U$. If $U,V\in\mathscr{U}$, and $U\ne V$, then $U\cap V=\varnothing$, so $x_U\ne x_V$. Thus, $\varphi$ is injective. It follows that $|\mathscr{U}|\le|D|\le\aleph_0$, i.e., that $\mathscr{U}$ is countable.

---

To answer your last question (while sticking with my notation), $\{U\cap D:U\in\mathscr{U}\}$ is not a partition of $D$: it is a pairwise disjoint collection of non-empty subsets of $D$, but in general its union is not $D$.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 1-1 correspondence really, but an injection: let $D$ be dense, and $\mathcal{U}$ be a family of pairwise disjoint non-empty open sets.

Using AC we pick for each $U \in \mathcal{U}$ some $f(U) \in D\cap U$ which is possible as $D$ is dense.

Then if $U \neq U' \in \mathcal{U}$ we know that $U \cap U' = \emptyset$ so $f(U) \neq f(U')$ and so $f$ is 1-1 from $\mathcal{U}$ to $D$. So $|\mathcal{U}| \le |D|$

If $X$ is separable, we can pick a fixed countable $D$ and then for any such pdof (pairwise disjoint (non-empty) open family) $\mathcal{U}$ we get by the previous that $|\mathcal{U}| \le \aleph_0$ and we're done. QED: A separable space is ccc.